# Using .net core appsettings with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, .net-6.0

I have a lot of configuration objects that get populated by reading an appsettings file.  Similar to this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<VaRideshare.Service.Common.Provider.Google.GoogleApiConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleApiConfiguration"));
```

I see where environment variables get defined in Elastic Beanstalk but is it possible to use a production appSettings file to define the configuration or do I need to break apart my appsettings file into individual environment variables in order to access them?

Comment: There's nothing special about appsettings. It's just a common file name for a JSON settings file. .NET Core reads settings from *many* sources, including environment variables, settings files, the command line and even AWS settings services. The default setup reads settings from appsettings, environment variables and command-line arguments, with later ones overriding previews values. If you set an env variable you can easily override existing settings

Comment: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) explains how configuration works and how to use multiple settings files, or name environment variables so they're picked up by your application. That article points to some third-party config providers but there are many more. AWS provides a [configuration provider for AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-configuration-provider-for-aws-systems-manager/) too.